# How to display the TID of a term reference field in a content type?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, 8

In **Drupal 8**, I have a blog content type with a taxonomy term reference field called category.

How can I print out the Term ID of the taxonomy term of the category field in my **node.html.twig** file.

I can print the term name using **{{ content.field_category }}** but I also want to print out the term ID which should be a unique number. How should I go about doing this as I have search for days without any clue?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, I was able to print the term ID of the category field using:

**{{ node.field_category.entity.tid.value }}** as I realised I was looking in the wrong direction. Drupal 8 use entity reference only so I needed to call the TID from the referenced entity which of course is a taxonomy term in my category field.

Answer (score 1):

One "hacky" way to do this:

```
{# First step: capture the rendered output of the internal path link for a term #}  
{% set tid %}{{ content.field_category.0['#url'] }}{% endset %}

{# Second step: do some string processing on the captured output, removing the /taxonomy/term/ prefix and getting the TID #}  
{{ tid|trim|replace({ '/taxonomy/term/' : '' }) }}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the following

```
{{ content.field_category[0]['#options']['entity'].id() }}
```